# An application of Hahn-Banach to analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

Given a compact $K\subset\mathbb{C}$, Let $A(K)=\mathcal{C}^0(K)\cap \mathcal{H}(\text{int}(K))$.
I am asked to prove that, for every $a\in K$, there is a probability (Borel) measure $\mu_a$ on $\partial K$ such that $\int_{\partial K} fd\mu_a=f(a)$ for every $f\in A(K)$.

My idea was: first, note that $A(K)$ is a closed subset of $\mathcal{C}^0(\partial K)$ equipped with the usual norm, bu Cauchy inequalities. Now the evaluation in $a$ is a bounded linear functional on $A(K)$, which can be extended to a bounded linear functional on $\mathcal{C}^0(\partial K)$ by Hahn-Banach. By Riesz's representation theorem, there's a Borel regular measure $\mu$ on $\partial K$ such that $f(a)=\int fd\mu$.
Since the evalutaion, as a linear functional, is easily seen to have norm $1$, $||\mu||=1$ (where $||\mu||=|\mu|(X)$, i.e. the total variation norm). The only thing left to prove is that $\mu$ is a real unsigned measure. I have no idea on how to proceed, an hint would be very helpful.

In the particular case $K=\mathbb{D}$, the result is easy: the measure is
induced by the poisson kernel, i.e.
$$f(a)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(e^{it})\text{Re}\left(\frac{e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z}\right)\frac{dt}{2\pi}$$
However, I don't think this approach is useful in general (one could use it if $\partial K$ where sufficiently regular and $K$ simply connected maybe, using the conformal map to the disk to translate the poisson kernel, butit does not seem to work in general)

Comment: You already have the $\mu$ is a Borel regular measure. What else would you need to make it a "real unsigned measure"?

Comment: @MartinArgerami in this context, $\mu$ is a complex Borel measure, if that's what you're asking

Comment: But your map $f\longmapsto f(a)$ is positive. RM gives you the positivity of $\mu$ automatically.

Comment: @MartinArgerami How is that so, if $f(a)\in\mathbb{C}?$ What order are you placing on $\mathbb{C}$ in order the evaluation positive? Apologies if this is trivial.

Comment: The usual order. Your measure satisfies that $\int_{\partial K} f\,d\mu\geq0$ whenever $f\geq0$. This automatically implies that $\mu$ is a positive measure, by the actual construction of $\mu$ in RM.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Yes, you are right, don't know what I was thinking. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it: instead of thinking about holomorphic functions, let us think about harmonic functions (and so about $\Re(f),\Im(f)$). Let $h(K)$ be the set of functions continuous on $K$ harmonic on $\text{int}(K)$. The maximum principle implies that $h(K)$ is a closed subspace of $\mathcal{C}^0(K,\mathbb{R})$. As before, the evaluation $e_a$ is a continuous (real) linear functional on a $K$, with norm $1$, and it is positive. We can now apply the *real* version of Riesz-Markov representation theorem, giving us a positive probability measure $\mu_a$ such that

$$u(a)=\int_{\partial K}u(t)d\mu_a(t)\\
v(a)=\int_{\partial K}v(t)d\mu_a(t)$$

And thus, considering $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$, the result follows.